# Troubles with "make" command to install R-3.2.1

Tags: r

I tried to install the [R-3.2.1](http://www.vps.fmvz.usp.br/CRAN/src/base/R-3/R-3.2.1.tar.gz) in my Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, but I had troubles with "make" command. How can I install in a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is via [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/rrutter):

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:marutter/rrutter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y r-base
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid this dependency resolving issues...simple way to install R in Ubuntu is as below:

load the text file /etc/apt/sources.list in your editor. You must have root privileges, though because it is a system file.

- First open a terminal (Applications - Accessories - terminal).
- Then open /etc/apt/sources.list with root privileges: type in the terminal

gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

You will need to give your user password (this assumes you are a user with root privileges) and then the file will load in the editor "gedit".

At the end of the file, add below line :

deb http:///bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/

run below commands interminal
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base

•   Now to start an R prompt in your terminal prompt type "R" and hit "enter" key

Comment: The version of R in this case is 3.0.2 and I need the 3.2.1 version.